# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.60-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)

Tags: java, oracle

I just want to 
 run ORACLE SQL Developer 4.0.2.12.21 
 in OpenSuSE 13.11.10   - 64x

> linux-l4i7:/home/suse/bin/sqldeveloper # ./sqldeveloper.sh

```
    > Oracle SQL Developer
    > Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
    >
    >
    >
    > LOAD TIME : 448#
    ># A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    >
    >#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f084ebe7250, pid=20064, tid=139674518972160
    >#
    ># JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_60-b19) (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
    ># Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.60-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed >oops)
    ># Problematic frame:
    ># C  0x00007f084ebe7250
    >#
    ># Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try >"ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
    >#
    >># An error report file with more information is saved as:
    ># /home/suse/bin/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/hs_err_pid20064.log
    >#
    ># If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    >#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    >#
    >/home/suse/bin/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/../../ide/bin/launcher.sh: line 1193: 20064 >Aborted                 ${JAVA} "${APP_VM_OPTS[@]}" ${APP_ENV_VARS} -classpath >${APP_CLASSPATH} ${APP_MAIN_CLASS} "${APP_APP_OPTS[@]}"
```

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread is native thread

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x00007f084ebe7250

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000001, RBX=0x00007f0882166a38, RCX=0x00007f0882166700, RDX=0x00007f084ebe7250
RSP=0x00007f0882165f18, RBP=0x00007f08ba697308, RSI=0x0000000000000001, RDI=0x00007f0865061140
R8 =0x00007f08b42af7f0, R9 =0x0000000000000001, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000246
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00007f08ba6972e8, R14=0x0000000000000004, R15=0x000000000000001e
RIP=0x00007f084ebe7250, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000014
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f0882165f18)
0x00007f0882165f18:   00007f08ba485e92 00007f0882166700
0x00007f0882165f28:   00007f0882166700 0000000000000000
0x00007f0882165f38:   0000000000000000 00007f08ba8bc000
0x00007f0882165f48:   00007f08ba891df0 00007f0882166700






Instructions: (pc=0x00007f084ebe7250)
0x00007f084ebe7230:   
[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xb]

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007f0882166a38 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00007f0882166700 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00007f084ebe7250 is an unknown value

Card table byte_map: [0x00007f08b8010000,0x00007f08b8221000] byte_map_base: 0x00007f08b7a20000

Polling page: 0x00007f08ba8b9000

Code Cache  [0x00007f08b1000000, 0x00007f08b1470000, 0x00007f08b4000000)
 total_blobs=1875 nmethods=1189 adapters=639 free_code_cache=44718Kb largest_free_block=45718336

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 13.402 Thread 0x00007f08b409f000 nmethod 1371 0x00007f08b1421390 code [0x00007f08b14214c0, 0x00007f08b1421538]
Event: 13.402 Thread 0x00007f08b409f000 1372             java.util.Date::getTime (5 bytes)
Event: 13.402 Thread 0x00007f08b409f000 nmethod 1372 0x00007f08b1421150 code [0x00007f08b1421280, 0x00007f08b14212f8]
Event: 13.403 Thread 0x00007f08b409f000 1373             org.openide.util.NbCollections$4$1::hasNext (13 bytes)
Event: 13.403 Thread 0x00007f08b409f000 nmethod 1373 0x00007f08b1406f50 code [0x00007f08b14070a0, 0x00007f08b1407178]
Event: 13.404 Thread 0x00007f08b409f000 1374             javax.ide.extension.spi.DefaultElementContext::getVisitorForStartElementImpl (243 bytes)
Event: 13.542 Thread 0x00007f08b409f000 nmethod 1374 0x00007f08b1454e50 code [0x00007f08b1455180, 0x00007f08b1456b40]
Event: 13.542 Thread 0x00007f08b409f000 1375             oracle.javatools.data.ChangeBuffer::addChangeInfo (10 bytes)
Event: 13.546 Thread 0x00007f08b409f000 nmethod 1375 0x00007f08b1343710 code [0x00007f08b1343880, 0x00007f08b1343ba8]
Event: 13.546 Thread 0x00007f08b409f000 1376             oracle.javatools.data.ChangeInfo::<init> (85 bytes)
```

Comment: What's the question andbwhat have you done yourself?

Comment: Hi, It should run normaly, just this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a native Java crash. It can be a Bug in the JVM, the netbeans launcher, maybe some incompatibilities in your environment (especially wrong or missing libraries).

Did this sqldeveloper installation include a JRE? You might want to change the script to point to a system JVM. The hs_err file looks a bit incomplete. It should for example contain a list of loaded libraries and the path of the actual Java binary. Did you cut that out or is it missing?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, yes, I cutted it because is too long and StackOverflow limit the space of the question, 

I will try to share the complete file

Answer (score 0):

Might not be related but this worked for me

```
gksudo gedit /usr/bin/sqldeveloper
```

Then these 2 lines at the top:

```
unset GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

Found the answer here
http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2014/01/28/fixing-sql-developer-4-0/